# Wrongful ban on SO chat for a silly reason?

Tags: support, chat, ban

Today I was banned from StackOverflow chat for 30 minutes for "posting inappropriate content". Transcript (with the irrelevant bits edited out) as follows:

[image: loungec]

All I had said was "guys plz ban", jokingly referring to Don's message. I was not referring to myself and everyone knew that.

Honestly it would have been funny to  me if the ban was for maybe 2 mins, but half an hour? All respect to BoltClock and the mods that help this community run, but it just seems to me that was a bit childish. Is this kind of behavior condoned?

Comment: If you asked for a ban and five people flagged what you said, then the system would have given you the 30 minute ban, not a mod (assuming I understand the system correctly).

Comment: I was there, I can testify. This was mod abuse. We should take this seriously.

Comment: @Catija Ah I see. The mod himself was clearly present though so I'm inclined to believe it was his own action.

Comment: ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​You should take this to [Meta Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions), it's a site specific issue.

Comment: Don't go near that particular  chat room if want to have nice time here...

Comment: Not sure what you expect us to do. Yell at the childish users? Spank them? Really. If you can't handle their games, simply don't be in the room with them.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Are you talking to me? I have no problem with the users in the Lounge. I just assumed this was a case of admin abuse and wanted to get clarification.

Comment: The "automatically suspended" should clarify that normal high rep users clicked "valid" on a flag - mod banning is manual.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Not 100% sure on that - if a mod validates a flag, that action is binding, and will probably produce the same message (vs a moderator actually going to a chat profile and suspending from there).

Comment: "guys plz ban" (if that is what you said) doesn't seem to be an obvious joke to me. It reads like a serious request. While it was perhaps daft for people to fulfil your request, you *did request it*. Be careful what you wish for ;)

Comment: @James I was referring to another user, who had quoted something that got another user banned a couple minutes before (who, I suspect, faced a rather similar situation to mine). I realize it does look like a serious request when taken out of context, but I can assure you I was joking :)

Comment: @nick yeah fair enough. I can see your issue is why a mod would ban, rather than fellow punsters :) (Which Anna's answer resolved)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You picked up 7 flags on that message from your friendly neighborhood chat users, and that dropped you in the ban zone.

I can see how you'd assume BoltClock jumped to suspend you, but I'm glad and not surprised to see that he did, in fact, know better than to abuse his diamond.

Comment: Wait, mods aren't allowed to suspend users who ask to be suspended!?

Comment: @Servy Mods need to exercise good judgement on the nature of such requests. :)

Comment: Ah, I see. But aren't flags an indicator for a mod to come and review the situation? I still don't understand why I would be banned for inappropriate content when there clearly wasn't any.

Comment: @nick Enough flags = automatic ban by the chat system. It doesn't require diamond-moderator involvement. That's community-driven moderation for ya. There's also no way to see in the room itself if someone's suspended, so it just looks like the message was removed.

Comment: YAY! So I do understand the flag system in chat :D

Comment: Glad to hear there wasn't any admin abuse in this situation

Comment: Amassing 7 flags on a single message. That's an achievement worth putting in your resume.

Comment: Well, mod can unsuspend a user, no? Bolt could end this childish game, so...

Comment: @ShadowWizard Yes, if the mod knows the user is suspended in the first place.

Comment: What? Mod doesn't get indication that a user is suspended?

Comment: @ShadowWizard In chat? Not even a little bit.

Comment: Oh. So if this happens and user want to appeal the suspension he/she needs to go through the whole flagging procedure? Maybe time for a feature request...

Comment: @ShadowWizard It's half an hour... in chat. Not the end of the world. The user just needs to wait.

Comment: Well, in this specific case the user isn't really innocent, but suppose some users abuse that power to suspend a new user just for fun. That's not nice, and having a quick way to report/appeal such a thing would be expected.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Yes, probably. But, chat moderation in general needs lots of love. There's no point in having an appeal process if there is nobody there to look at it. The underlying assumption of chat is that diamond mods are probably not there... and by the time one might come along, the suspension will expire on its own anyway. In short, meh.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Agreed, it would be nice to have an option to appeal a ban. Luckily the automatic ban is only 30 minutes.

Comment: @ShadowWizard We don't suspend people for fun. And aside from kicking, none of us have unilateral powers to do that anyway. I wasn't here when this happened, but it certainly looks like the OP asked to be banned and enough of us granted that without realizing that it was a joke.

Comment: @Mysticial Har har

Comment: @Mysticial If even half of them weren't laughing I'll eat my hat

Comment: So a mod can suspend another mod in chat?

Comment: @PythonMaster In principle, sure. However, same as with a chat suspension it doesn't do much since the suspended mod can just unsuspend themselves.